# How to find the diff history of specific line in a file using git?

Tags: linux, git, command-line, command

I want to find a list of history for a specific line in a file for example

```
file: something.txt

1/2
line 1: // change comment to 1

2/15
line 1: // change comment to 2

12/15
line 1: // change comment to 4
```

If I do `git blame` it only shows `12/15` entry, and if there is tons of commit between `2/15` and `12/15` then `git log` is not really useful

Can someone give me some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example:

```
git log -L 1,1:something.txt
```

From the [documentaion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

> **-L <start>,<end>:<file>**
>
> **-L :<funcname>:<file>**
>
> Trace the evolution of the line range given by "<start>,<end>" (or the function name regex <funcname>) within the <file>. You may not give any pathspec limiters. This is currently limited to a walk starting from a single revision, i.e., you may only give zero or one positive revision arguments. You can specify this option more than once.